# Keep pandas DataFrame rows in df2 for each row in df1 with timedelta

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two pandas dataframes. I would like to keep all rows in `df2` where `Type` is equal to `Type` in `df1` AND `Date` is between `Date` in `df1` (- 1 day or + 1 day). How can I do this?

**df1**

```
   IBSN  Type          Date
0     1     X    2014-08-17
1     1     Y    2019-09-22
```

**df2**

```
   IBSN  Type          Date
0     2     X    2014-08-16
1     2     D    2019-09-22
2     9     X    2014-08-18
3     3     H    2019-09-22
4     3     Y    2019-09-23
5     5     G    2019-09-22
```

**res**

```
   IBSN  Type          Date
0     2     X    2014-08-16 <-- keep because Type = df1[0]['Type'] AND Date = df1[0]['Date'] - 1
1     9     X    2014-08-18 <-- keep because Type = df1[0]['Type'] AND Date = df1[0]['Date'] + 1
2     3     Y    2019-09-23 <-- keep because Type = df1[1]['Type'] AND Date = df1[1]['Date'] + 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import timedelta

# create dummy data
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1, 'X', '2014-08-17'], [1, 'Y', '2019-09-22']], columns=['IBSN', 'Type', 'Date'])
df1['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Date'])  # might not be necessary if your Date column already contain datetime objects

df2 = pd.DataFrame([[2, 'X', '2014-08-16'], [2, 'D', '2019-09-22'], [9, 'X', '2014-08-18'], [3, 'H', '2019-09-22'], [3, 'Y', '2014-09-23'], [5, 'G', '2019-09-22']], columns=['IBSN', 'Type', 'Date'])
df2['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Date'])  # might not be necessary if your Date column already contain datetime objects


# add date boundaries to the first dataframe
df1['Date_from'] = df1['Date'].apply(lambda x: x - timedelta(days=1))
df1['Date_to'] = df1['Date'].apply(lambda x: x + timedelta(days=1))

# merge the date boundaries to df2 on 'Type'. Filter rows where date is between
# data_from and date_to (inclusive). Drop 'date_from' and 'date_to' columns
df2 = df2.merge(df1.loc[:, ['Type', 'Date_from', 'Date_to']], on='Type', how='left')
df2[(df2['Date'] >= df2['Date_from']) & (df2['Date'] <= df2['Date_to'])].\
    drop(['Date_from', 'Date_to'], axis=1)
```

Note that according to your logic, row 4 in df2 (3  Y   2014-09-23) should not remain as its date (2014) is not in between the given dates in df1 (year 2019).

Comment: Yep, the 2014 was a typo. I've fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: @RubenB, in my data set df2 have A,B,C,D,E villages 2 times and in df1 data I have only A,B and C villages. I want result as A,B and C data which is in df2 data which is 2 times repeated. how can we get ?

Answer (score 1):

Assume `Date` columns in both dataframes are already in dtype `datetime`. I would construct `IntervalIndex` to assign to index of `df1`. `Map` columns `Type` of `df1` to `df2`. Finally check equality to create mask to slice

```
iix = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(df1.Date + pd.Timedelta(days=-1), 
                                   df1.Date + pd.Timedelta(days=1), closed='both')
df1 = df1.set_index(iix)
s = df2['Date'].map(df1.Type)
df_final = df2[df2.Type == s]

Out[1131]:
   IBSN Type       Date
0     2    X 2014-08-16
2     9    X 2014-08-18
4     3    Y 2019-09-23
```

Comment: in my data set df2 have A,B,C,D,E villages 2 times and in df1 data I have only A,B and C villages. I want result as A,B and C data which is in df2 data .

Comment: >>> import pandas as pd
>>> import numpy as np
>>> df2=pd.read_excel("/home/desktop/Desktop/df.xlsx")
>>> df2
  Village  Area
0       A     1
1       B     2
2       C     3
3       D     4
4       E     5
5       A     6
6       B     7
7       C     8
8       D     9
9       E    10
>>> df1=pd.read_excel("/home/desktop/Desktop/df1.xlsx")
>>> df1
  Village  Area
0       A     1
1       B     2
2       C     3
>>>

Comment: @Kiran: it seems not difficult. However, please post a new question with more detai. Especially with detail expected output